# Summing up columns and getting average from a file having line breaks

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file as with line gaps: (And the file may not also contain line gaps)

```
34

12

45
```

How to get the average value out of it?
I tried with

```
echo $(awk  'BEGIN{max=0}{if(($1)>max)  max=($1)}END {print max}' filename)
```

It gives 45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get average use:

```
awk 'NF{sum += $1; ++n} END{if (n) printf "%.2f\n", sum/n}' file
```

```
30.33
```

We are using conditional block `NF{...}` which is making sure to execute if there is at least 1 field in a line meaning this block will not execute for blank lines.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava  could you give a quick explanation on this. and why n is not 6 in this case (isn't it taking the gaps)

Comment: could you take a look into this also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913529/getting-a-row-whose-specific-given-column-has-max-value-in-bash-script