# Getting a row whose specific given column has max value in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have file as (the spacing may not be regular)

```
a  34 4
b 34 5
c 4  123
d 100   34
e 1  23
```

Now how to get the row having the max value according to the column say, 2nd column using bash script.
The output should be :

```
d 100   34
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work even if all of your key values are negative and won't print a blank line if your input file is empty:

```
$ awk '(NR==1) || ($2 > max){max=$2; rec=$0} END{if (NR) print rec}' file
d 100   34
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this awk:

```
awk '$2 > max{max=$2; r=$0} END{print r}' file
```

```
d 100   34
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to awk:

```sh
sort -k2nr file | head -1
```